# is there any configuration I could do to make logcat show AndroidRuntime exception?

Tags: android-logcat, runtimeexception

There are many times I encountered an uncaught exception in android development, and it caused the thread to exit without further debugging information. Currently the message in my logcat looks like this:

> 10-24 21:06:56.762: W/dalvikvm(8806): threadid=25: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x410a8438)

However when I searched on the internet trying to find how to debug similar messages, people typically posted something like"

```
04-25 19:35:02.353: W/dalvikvm(5650): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
04-25 19:35:02.393: E/AndroidRuntime(5650): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-25 19:35:02.393: E/AndroidRuntime(5650): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.least/com.example.least.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
04-25 19:35:02.393: E/AndroidRuntime(5650):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
04-25 19:35:02.393: E/AndroidRuntime(5650):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
04-25 19:35:02.393: E/AndroidRuntime(5650):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
04-25 19:35:02.393: E/AndroidRuntime(5650):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
04-25 19:35:02.393: E/AndroidRuntime(5650):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-25 19:35:02.393: E/AndroidRuntime(5650):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-25 19:35:02.393: E/AndroidRuntime(5650):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-25 19:35:02.393: E/AndroidRuntime(5650):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-25 19:35:02.393: E/AndroidRuntime(5650):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-25 19:35:02.393: E/AndroidRuntime(5650):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-25 19:35:02.393: E/AndroidRuntime(5650):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-25 19:35:02.393: E/AndroidRuntime(5650):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-25 19:35:02.393: E/AndroidRuntime(5650): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
04-25 19:35:02.393: E/AndroidRuntime(5650):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
04-25 19:35:02.393: E/AndroidRuntime(5650):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
04-25 19:35:02.393: E/AndroidRuntime(5650):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
04-25 19:35:02.393: E/AndroidRuntime(5650):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
04-25 19:35:02.393: E/AndroidRuntime(5650):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
04-25 19:35:02.393: E/AndroidRuntime(5650):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
04-25 19:35:02.393: E/AndroidRuntime(5650):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
```

The latter  clearly contained more useful debugging information as typically suggested by this "Caused by" clause, whereas my logcat output did nothing but obfuscate the real problem underneath, despite the fact that I have already set the debug level to be verbose.

Is this a configuration problem? How can I configure my logcat to show something that's more suggestive?